# MS-Access iif statement convert to T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, iif

Trying to convert access iif statement

```
IIf(FD.[Sales_Value] = 0, 'Component',
    (IIf(FD.[Lines] = 0,    
        IIf(FD.[Sales_Value] = FD.[Gross_Contribution],
            'Composite', 'N'),
        'N')
    )
) AS Composite,
```

I have this at the moment but it doesn't like it

```
CASE WHEN FD.[Sales_Value] = 0 THEN 'Component'
ELSE CASE WHEN FD.[Lines] = 0 THEN
        CASE WHEN FD.[Sales_Value] = FD.[Gross_Contribution] THEN 'Composite' ELSE 'N' --END
        ELSE
            'N'
        END 
END
    AS Composite
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, much better readable:

```
CASE 
    WHEN FD.[Sales_Value] = 0 THEN 'Component'
    WHEN FD.[Lines] = 0 AND FD.[Sales_Value] = FD.[Gross_Contribution] 
       THEN 'Composite' 
    ELSE 'N'
END
    AS Composite
```